# how to open facebook external application in ionic app

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, ionic-framework

I am making an ionic app and in this app menu I have created an option of about us and in this option, I want to open facebook external app I am new in ionic any know how to open facebook external app with facebook page URL so please tell me.
Thanks in advance please help me

Comment: Only for Android devices? Or iOS too?

Comment: only for android devices

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install a [plugin to open external URLs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.9.0/cordova/inappbrowser/inappbrowser.html).

As described in the [wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/cordova/InAppBrowser), there are several ways to launch the InAppBrowser and all perform differently.

For your case should be:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('https://apps.facebook.com/app_name', '_system', 'location=yes'); return false;">Open Facebook App</a>
```

Comment: well I don't want to open my URL in browser I want to open facebook app on click

Comment: Please detail that better on your question

Comment: sorry for that but sir please tell me how can i open facebook app

Answer (score -2):

This will redirect you facebook from your ionic app:

```
 $scope.open=function(){
        window.location.href ="https://www.facebook.com";
      }
```

Comment: but how we can get back to our app